# Empty Table after making my CHOICES in the model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have this django model for category :

```
class CategoryModel(models.Model):
CATEGORY_CHOICES = [
    ('first','hardware'),
    ('second','software'),
    ('third','network')
]
category = models.CharField(max_length=15,null=False,blank=False,choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'categories_table'
```

On the data base it creates the table but its empty , and i want it to have three instances of each choice i defiend in the CATEGORY_CHOICES

I wanted to have like auto filled , without i manually create the instances

Comment: Since you want to have three instances, using a model is a bit strange. Either you have `choices` wich means that the options are *fixed*, or you have a model, which means you can create/update records. `choices` does not mean Django generates records, it means it restricits the values, so in this case, `category` can be only on of these three.

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem , oh i thought that choices = something makes like a select option where u have your values and then you chose from it

Comment: it makes indeed a select option, so in the admin for example of your `CategoryModel`, if you want to select a category, it will list these three options. The point is that you use it on a *category model*. That does not make much sense, you either use a model with a `ForeignKey` for the categories, or you work with such choice field on all models that have to refer to a category.

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem exactly , im using it as a "foreignKey" for other model , thats why i wanted to have it auto filled on the db , so i could do " categorymodel.objects.all()  "on my form

Answer (score 1):

It makes not much sense to have *both* `choices` *and* a `CategoryModel` model. Usually it is one, or the other, not both.

Indeed, normally one either sets a `Category` and then for example a `Product` with:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'categories_table'


class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

then you can for example create the categories in the shell with:

```
Category.objects.bulk_create(
    [Category(name=name) for name in ['hardware', 'software', 'network']]
)
```

If you will not do much querying on categories, or count by categories, or aggregate over categories, you can also decide to *omit* the `Category` model, and just make a field that pricks predefined choices, like:

```
CATEGORY_CHOICES = [
    ('hardware', 'hardware'),
    ('software', 'software'),
    ('network', 'network'),
]


# no Category model, a direct field of Product
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
```

I would however recommend the first approach.